# onClick Function running while Rendering Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, mapping, emoji

### onCLick handler running while rendering component, is there any error in code?

```
class MappedEmoji extends React.Component{
    render(){
        const data = this.props.emoji.map(emoji => {
            return(
                <span onClick={this.props.handleClick(emoji)}  className="myEmoji">{emoji}</span>
            )
            });

        return(
            <div> {data}</div>
        )
    }

}
class StickersComponent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            Emoji:["","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],
        };
       this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    handleClick(emoji){
        console.log(emoji);
    }
    render(){       
        return(
            <div className="stickers555">
                <div className="_emoji">
                {
                        <MappedEmoji emoji={this.state.Emoji}
                        handleClick = {this.handleClick}/>
                }
                </div>
            </div>

        )
    }
}
  ReactDOM.render(<StickersComponent />, document.getElementById('App'))
```

above is a code rendering all Emoji's perfectly, but as onclick handler binds to onClick function its not binding or may have some other problem. as click handler is bind , i am getting all emoji's in console while rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling as a callback.

```
<span onClick={() => this.props.handleClick(emoji)}  className="myEmoji">
```

---

If you have to pass an argument to a function, and you don't want to invoke it immediately, you need to use callback.

```
   onClick={ () => yourFunction(argument1) }
```

Comment: now its Working as Expected after making callback. You was like lost after trying several times. Thank For Showing me Path @user9408899

Comment: yeah i already accept that. Accept button needs to wait for 10min :)

Comment: @RahulShahare I didn't know that :).